# How to process a 1GB text file with python

Tags: python, text-files

I am trying to process a text file of more than 1GB and saving the data in to Mysql database using python.

I had pasted some sample code below

```
import os
import MySQLdb as mdb

conn = mdb.connect(user='root', passwd='redhat', db='Xml_Data', host='localhost', charset="utf8")

file_path = "/home/local/user/Main/Module-1.0.4/file_processing/part-00000.txt"

file_open = open('part-00000','r')

for line in file_open:
    result_words = line.split('\t')
    query = "insert into PerformaceReport (campaignID, keywordID, keyword, avgPosition)"
    query += " VALUES (%s,%s,'%s',%s) " % (result_words[0],result_words[1],result_words[2],result_words[3])
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute( query )
    conn.commit()
```

Actually there are more than 18 columns the data is being inserted in to, i had just pasted only four(for example)

So when i run the above code the execution time is taking some `hours`

All my doubts are

1. Is there any alternate way for processing the 1GB text file in python very fastly ?
2. Is there any framework that process the 1GB text file and saves the data in to database very fastly ?
3. How to process a text file of large size(1GB) within minutes(is it possible) and save data in to database?
   All my concern about is , we need to process the 1GB file as fast as possible but not in hours

**Edited Code**

```
query += " VALUES (%s,%s,'%s',%s) " % (int(result_words[0] if result_words[0] != '' else ''),int(result_words[2] if result_words[2] != '' else ''),result_words[3] if result_words[3] != '' else '',result_words[4] if result_words[4] != '' else '')
```

Actually i am submitting the values in the above format(by checking the result existence)

Comment: Have you tried this approach and measured how well it performs? If you don't know what's the bottleneck in your program (disk, parsing the file, or storage in the db) then blindly optimizing one of them isn't going to give much of a speedup.

Comment: yeah i had tried above approach and it is taking more than 7 hrs ... so approached SO for exact way to process....

Comment: Why are you doing that stuff in your edit? That's what parsing the values as a parameter to the cursor is for - you don't have to worry about types -- **don't use string formatting to build SQL queries**

Comment: actually, this is not a valid code. `int('')` raises `ValueError`

Comment: actually sometimes,i am getting integer values from the list after splitting,hence i am converting that in to int data type(which i had created as a datatype for that field in database)

Comment: I mean some of the values i am converting to int are like this format actually '238973298','927432987','984732'..., so converting in to int

Comment: You don't need to convert them - stop using string formatting and use the correct format of `execute` - `cursor.execute(query, query_values)`

Comment: k fine,i code given by dikei, and getting the below errors except

Comment: mdb.Errors: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Errors'

Comment: Also displaying 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: @Kouripm: you're not even attempting to understand what yours or given to you code does.

Comment: Its not like that,i understood what the errors are!!!! but my intention of pasting here is just to show whats the result of the code given thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import MySQLdb as mdb
import csv

def read_file():
    file_path = "/home/local/user/Main/Module-1.0.4/file_processing/part-00000.txt"
    with open('part-00000','r') as infile:
        file_open= csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
        cache = []
        for line in file_open:
            cache.append(line)
            if len(cache) > 500:
                yield cache
                cache = []
        yield cache 

conn = mdb.connect(user='root', passwd='redhat', db='Xml_Data', host='localhost', charset="utf8")
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = "insert into PerformaceReport (campaignID, keywordID, keyword, avgPosition) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
for rows in read_file():
    try:
        cursor.executemany(query, rows)
    except mdb.Error:
        conn.rollback()
    else:
        conn.commit()
```

The code is untested and might contain minor errors, but should be faster, not as fast as using `LOAD DATA INFILE` though.

Comment: Fixed, thank guys. I'm also not sure if `executemany` can take generator, will check back later.

Comment: here in the above code u r are yielding a line but we need data from that line as i told u, i have many columns,i.e., by splitting the line, taking the individual elements and submitting to destination field as values. How thats works with just yield ?

Comment: @Kouripm instead of `yield line` you would change it to `yield line[0], line[23]` whatever...

Comment: @jon:oh fine, then i had pasted my original code which doesn't suits i think please have a look at above edited code

Comment: Also when i tried above example it is showing the error  except mdb.Errors:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Errors'

Comment: Also displaying 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: Since a huge commit also reduces performance, I've modified the script to only insert 500 rows for each commit.

Comment: @Dikei Really? The whole idea is the DB will know how to optimise the commit at the end. On a live system, putting chunks into a live table is a bad idea. Imagine 10 chunks, of which 3, 6 and 9 fail. Your code will still succeed although now you have no idea how to reverse the effect of that (unless you know how to remove certain chunks - which would then require more queries and potential locking etc...), and during that time, chunks would have been visible to queries... It just leads to a nightmare situation...

Comment: There's always trade off between performance and consistency. AFAIK, for maximum performance, the transaction should be smaller than  `innodb_log_buffer_size`. I don't have experience with system that require 1GB transaction, but for that much data, I don't think live update is a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

Bit of a wild guess, but I'd say the `conn.commit()` for every line in the file would make a big difference. Try moving it outside the loop. You also don't need to recreate the cursor in each iteration of the loop - just do it once before the loop.

Answer (score 2):

As well as what Tim has said, I would have a look at MySQL's [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html). Do any  necessary pre-processing in Python and write that to a separate file which MySQL has access to, then execute the appropriate query and let MySQL do the loading.

Or, possibly re-write the Python code to what it should be anyway (you should be passing the parameters as values, not doing string manipulation - SQL injection attacks for one):

```
query = 'insert into something(a, b, c, d) values(%s, %s, %s, %s)'
with open('file.tab') as fin:
    values = (row.split('\t')[:4] for row in fin)
    cursor.executemany(query, values)
```